# Unity Engine. Rotation calculation issue. Rigidbodies and rotation with an object

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, rotation, physics, rigid-bodies

I´ve got some problems with rotations. So, I´ve got a ship, imagine it as a container, I´m trying to get everything within that container to follow the position and rotation of that container. These internal objects are also rigidbodies that can freely move.

So imagine that within the ship there is a table and a cup, both objects rigidbodies. If you are within the ship you can push over both objects, but while the ship moves, it will "drag" them with it.
So the table and cup have to always stay in the correct position, no matter how much the ship moves and rotates. And to clarify, I won´t be able to parent them either, they have to stay separate in this case. Hope I explained that right!

So, for now, I was able to achieve the detection of objects within the ship and follow correctly the position. But the rotation, using rotateAround three times with each axis (Which in itself might be incredibly wrong already lol) even though it seemingly works, it´s always slightly off. And on bigger rotations just breaks fully.

Which does make sense I guess but I still don´t manage to think of a way to get this to behave right.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: _"I won´t be able to parent them either"_ - I had a similar issue.  For my [flight sim](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2021/10/17/flight-sim-project-update/) I used Unity [Parent Constraints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ParentConstraint.html).   Objects that were independent in the Editor but somewhat parented during gameplay whilst allowing independence.  e.g. in the plane you can see that the landing gear moves up and down freely due to "suspension".

Comment: Am I doing something wrong then? So, one of the things I tried was using Parent constraints, issues was that since I wanted the contained gameobjects to still obey physics independently I couldn´t get that result due to the parent constraint freezing objects in place. Stopping rigidbody forces.
To make more sense out of what I´m saying, I wanted contained objects to still be able to be affected by physics while at the same time being translated by the ship. So let´s say a ball should be able to continue rolling around while being dragged by transform. If that makes any sense?

Comment: OK, so in my landing gear case I have 2x 3D objects and a few components: _the wheel (3D geometry);_ the _strut_ (3D geometry) that holds the wheel; and a Unity _wheel collider_ (which is naturally invisible) component.  **1)** the wheel collider compnent does all the physics and is calculated first and works out where the "wheel" _should be in space_.  **2)** I have a simple `FixedUpdate` script that copies the wheel collider's 3D position to my wheel 3D object - boom! So now my wheel's 3D mesh shares the origin of the collider and sits nicely on the ground.

Comment: ... **3)** finally a **position constraint** between shaft and wheel ensures that the shaft is always connected to the wheel as it bobs up and down (I could have done this in code but a zero-code option is always nice).  This was necessary as both shaft and wheel share the same parent.  If I didn't have the constraint the wheel would appear to have an invisible shaft connected to it.

Comment: Your case is kind of like my landing gear's wheel.  The wheel is still a child of the plane and so moves with it _**but**_ it has the freedom of bouncing.   Like the wheel collider, it essentially does its own thing and it knows where it is in the world, we update the 3D model by applying a relative position.  I wonder if you could keep track of cups and tables with their relative positions when applying physics adding in the ships forces.  Placing the updated cups and tables you again add the relative position to the ship's?

Comment: BTW, one trick in space simulators (particularly Kerbal Space Program) when dealing with very large distances or very fast moving objects is to have a _local frame of reference._   If you are inside the ship and there is no window to look out of, you could disregard the ships position on the ocean and just worry about the inside.  Of course you will still need to consider ship sway on objects inside - we still want that cup to slide off the table during heavy seas! :)